# Getting error for datetime in python

Tags: python, appium

I have a file named global.py and a function to create report :

```
import datetime

class customFail(Exception):pass

def createReport(myModule,iOSDevice,iOSVersion):
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    resultPath="../Results"
    resultFile="Result_%d_%d_%d_%d_%d_%d.html" % (now.day,now.month,now.year,now.hour,now.minute,now.second)
    fileName="%s/%s" % (resultPath,resultFile)

    fNameObj=open("../Results/resfileName.txt","w")     #Writing result filename temporary 
    fNameObj.write(fileName)                            #in a file to access this filename by other functions (rePass,resFail)

    fileObj=open(fileName,"w")
    fileObj.write("<html>")
    fileObj.write("<body bgcolor=\"Azure\">")
    fileObj.write("<p>                                                           </p>")
    fileObj.write("<table width=\"600\" border=\"5\">");
    fileObj.write("<tr style=\"background-color:LemonChiffon;\">")
    fileObj.write("<td width=\"40%\"><b>Module : </b>"+ myModule+"</td>")
    fileObj.write("<td width=\"30%\"><b>Time : </b>"+ now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")+"</td>")
    fileObj.write("</tr>")
    fileObj.write("<tr>")
    fileObj.write("</tr>")
    fileObj.write("</table>")
    fileObj.write("<table width=\"600\" border=\"5\">");
    fileObj.write("<tr style=\"background-color:BurlyWood;\">")
    fileObj.write("<td width=\"70%\"><b>Device : </b>"+ iOSDevice+" - <b>  Version : </b>"+ iOSVersion+"</td>")
    fileObj.write("</tr>")
    fileObj.write("</table>")
    #fileObj.write("<br>")
```

and a script file where i call this function called scripts.py

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/admin/Desktop/_Suite/Global Scripts/')
from funcLib import *
from myGlobal import *



wd = deviceSelection();
iOSVersion="i7"
iOSDevice="iPhone"
modName="BAT"
suiteStartTime=0

def main():
   start() 
   fntesttrial();
   finish(); 

def  start():
       global modName,suiteStartTime
       global appName,ctx_app,ctx_simulator
       suiteStartTime=time.time();
       createReport(modName,iOSDevice,iOSVersion)

stts=api_clr_acnt.fnClearAccount(myDict["UserName"],myDict["Password"],myDict["Environment"])

def fntesttrial():    
    try:
    wd.find_element_by_name("Accept").click()
    time.sleep(5)   
    wd.find_element_by_name("Sign In").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    wd.find_element_by_name("Need help?").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    wd.find_element_by_name("Close").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    finally:
        wd.quit()

main()
```

When I run this i am getting error like :

```
   now=datetime.datetime.now()
NameError: global name 'datetime' is not defined
```

I am not understanding why I am getting that error. Please help me since i am new to python.

Comment: Are you sure the other script is correctly saved , can you check if your main script is correctly picking the changed global.py?

Comment: Thanks Anand. I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

**I think you need to import datetime at the top of the script file (code block 2).** It gives you the error because datetime is indeed undefined in the script, as it hasn't been imported yet.
When you call "createReport()", "now" can't be defined, as it calls on the datetime module, which isn't imported.

If you wanted, you could write import datetime at the start of the method definition, but if you called the method twice, it would import datetime twice, so you're probably better off just importing it at the start of the second codeblock.